# How can I change the error message when using Google ReCaptcha version 2?

Tags: java, recaptcha

When multiple photos are selected for the Google ReCaptcha version 2, it  displays the following error message:

> "Multiple correct solutions required - please solve more."

How can i change the error message to be a custom message from my site?

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do server-side (at google). This rather might be done client-side by leveraging js to substitute HTML of the newly received reCaptcha pictures code:

### HTML

```
<div class="rc-imageselect-incorrect-response" style="">Multiple correct solutions required – please solve more.</div>
```

so you find this line of code and replace:

### JS (Jquery)

```
$('.rc-imageselect-incorrect-response').text('Custom message');
```

### When?

This action you should perform each time after XHR  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k=6LdYKQkTAAAAAD9K6-kHspFU... is complete. Yet since this ajax request is done by google's reCaptcha's api code, it's not that easy to catch up with it.