# noCaptcha: Prevent auto reload to catch failed attempt

Tags: recaptcha

I am integrating NoCaptcha to a website and want to catch failed captchas myself. Sadly, the "image selection" Captcha reloads immediately if it was not correctly solved.

So, if there is a challenge like "Pick all images showing coffee" and a user does not select all corresponding images correctly, the challenge reloads immediately. But I want the data (and form) to be posted anyway and check the Captcha correctness on my own.

Here is a minimalistic example of how it should work. I am sure, it would work, if the Captcha not reloaded instantly.

```
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "-----";
    $privatekey = "-----";
    try{
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            if(!$captcha){ exit; }
            $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if($response.success==false){
                // Do something
            } else {
                // Do something else
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <html lang="en"> 
            <head> 
                <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
                <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                 <form method="post" action="thisfile.php">
                   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $publickey; ?>"></div>
                   <input type="submit" value="Absenden" />
                 </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Do you know a way to prevent auto-reloading?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should know [operations](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge) behind reCaptcha. The Google reCaptcha API (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js) does all the work for reCaptcha operation; allowing **no site owner interactions** (except the site verify) with its reCaptcha.

So your attempts to `prevent reCaptcha auto-reloading` or similar whether break its operation or cause its misbehave toward end user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know that the API is designed to handle everything. But sometimes it is not desired that someone else does all the work for you ;)

Comment: @coroner, if you're so eager to intervene in google affairs, read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32627606/1230477) to other question.

Comment: great thing! Thank you very much! I will have a look at this :)